# Unable to track an instance of type in .Net core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am getting below error for one of the tables. the table doesn't have a primary key. How to handle this?
I am trying to add new row to the table.

Error

```
Unable to track an instance of type 'CommonDataZipInfo' because it does not have a primary key. 
Only entity types with primary keys may be tracked.'
```

DataContext.cs

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CommonDataZipInfo>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasNoKey();

            entity.ToTable("COMMON_DATA_ZIP_INFO");

            entity.Property(e => e.AddDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.ManuscriptNum)
                .HasColumnName("manuscript_num")
                .HasMaxLength(32)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.ZipfileName)
                .HasMaxLength(32)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });
```

Program.cs

```
 var CommonDataZipInfo = new CommonDataZipInfo()
 {
      ManuscriptNum = ManuscriptNum,
      ZipfileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName),
      AddDate = DateTime.Now
  };
  context.CommonDataZipInfo.Add(CommonDataZipInfo);
  context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Try reading this to run entity framework without tracking: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: I don't understand the question. You create a keyless entity type. It's well documented what you can and can't do with them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#keyless-entity-types-characteristics.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem here. These are my codes:

[...]

```
public partial class Radusergroup
{

        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Groupname { get; set; }
        public int Priority { get; set; }

}
```

[...]

[...]

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Radusergroup>(entity =>
{

                entity.HasNoKey();

                entity.ToTable("radusergroup");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.Username)
                    .HasName("username");

                entity.Property(e => e.Groupname)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("groupname")
                    .HasMaxLength(64)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("''''''");

                entity.Property(e => e.Priority)
                    .HasColumnName("priority")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'1'");

                entity.Property(e => e.Username)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("username")
                    .HasMaxLength(64)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("''''''");
});
```

[...]

Since you are not creating a key for your table, and sometimes, you can't change the database for some reason. In my case, this is a database which another application uses, so I don't want to compromise that other application, so my solution was simply turn my attribute "username" into a key, like this:

```
public partial class Radusergroup
{
   [Key]
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Groupname { get; set; }
   public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

and remove the HasNoKey on your context:

[...]

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Radusergroup>(entity =>
{

                //entity.HasNoKey();

                entity.ToTable("radusergroup");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.Username)
                    .HasName("username")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.Property(e => e.Groupname)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("groupname")
                    .HasMaxLength(64)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("''''''");

                entity.Property(e => e.Priority)
                    .HasColumnName("priority")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'1'");

                entity.Property(e => e.Username)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("username")
                    .HasMaxLength(64)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("''''''");
});
```

[...]

That will probably solve it.

Comment: Then what happens if you add 2 rows with same key?

Comment: Keys are meant to be unique. Add "IsUnique()" to your index. Check the edition I made to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

EF entity must need a primary key to operate and that key can exists or not in table.

From my experience(this is a workaround), I am trying to find a unique key using few columns and define that in model. Maybe you can use [keyless entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types).

Answer (score 2):

Just add [Key] attribute to some unique numeric field. It's no need to be defined as a PM on the server and remove entity.HasNoKey() call.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the various answers here helped me. Just adding my final solution.

As others have pointed out, the problem arises when the table does not have a Primary Key.
If you don't have the option to add a Key to you table or to change your Context (as suggested by Huander)
another option is to execute raw sql, like this:

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    var result = context.YourTable.FromSqlRaw("SELECT something FROM something");
}
```

Comment: Well, this only returns an `int` (# records affected), not the data. Not useful.

Comment: Yes you are correct @GertArnold I updated my answer to work for SELECT statements

Comment: And `Database.FromSqlRaw` doesn't exist. It's a `DbSet` method. It would really help to test code before posting.

Comment: My bad. Updated code works for me.

Comment: Now try with an entity without a key.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I simply added a primary key to the table. First you add id field in the table as int and set 'Is Identity' to yes. Then using Microsoft SQL Management Studio, right click on the id row and select "Set Primary Key". Then run Scaffold-DbContext to generate proper context class

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i resolve using below code

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CommonDataZipInfo>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.ManuscriptNum);

        entity.ToTable("COMMON_DATA_ZIP_INFO");

        entity.Property(e => e.AddDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

        entity.Property(e => e.ManuscriptNum)
            .HasColumnName("manuscript_num")
            .HasMaxLength(32)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        entity.Property(e => e.ZipfileName)
            .HasMaxLength(32)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    });
```

Add entity.HasKey(e => e.ManuscriptNum); if it is key value then added into your DbContext other wise you should have key value into your table.Entity Framework generally requires primary key columns or key columns in your database tables.

Answer (score -1):

Faced same issue in ASP.NET MVC EF Core6, now it's solved. You will face the problem of creating a keyless entity only if your DBContext derived class has Fluent APIs like .HasNoKey(), .HasIndex() etc. These fluent apis get added when u generated the DBContext class and entity using Scaffolding-Database command let. Don't use this. Because of these fluent apis, you are facing the problem. To fix this issue, please follow these steps:

1. Create your Database table as per your requirement either with key or without key.
2. Manually create the corresponding Entity class.
3. Create the DBContext derived class using Visual Studio. For this, select controller folder and select add new Controlleer, then select add read-write actions with Entity FrameworK.
4. In the dialog box, select he Entity created in step 2 and click on + sign to generate the DBContext derived class.
5. Now, DBContext derived class will not have those fluent api.
   Run the Application all crud operations will work fine.

Comment: Removing the fluent mappings is not a solution. The problem is that there is no key, with or without mappings. OP's only hope is to find a property (or combination of properties) that can be mapped as a unique key.